# Argument that the function is continuous from definition?

Tags: general-topology

If ${f,g : X\to \mathbb{R}}$ are continuous real-valued functions from a topological space $X$, then how can you show that
$$
h(x) := f(x) + g(x)
$$
is also continuous from definition (preimage of an open set is open)? I am aware you can simply do this by writing ${h}$ as a composition of continuous functions, but I have been trying to do it simply by arguing via this definition. I know I would need to show that for an interval ${(a,b)}$, ${h^{-1}((a,b))}$ is open in $X$ by using the fact pre-images of open intervals under ${f,g}$ are open in $X$, but cannot seem to write things out nicely in such a way that it works out.

Comment: At heart, it is due to the composition argument you've outlined. In particular, you need to show $+:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, and $(f,g):X\to\mathbb R^2$ defined as $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ is continuous using a definitional argument. This, of course, requires knowledge of the product topology on $\mathbb R^2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: $f(x)+g(x)<a\iff (\exists b\in\mathbb R)(f(x)<b \land g(x)<a-b)$.

Proof:

- $\implies$: if $f(x)+g(x)<a$ then $f(x)+g(x)+\delta=a$ for some $\delta>0$. Then $f(x)<f(x)+\delta/2$ and $g(x)=a-\delta-f(x)<a-\delta/2-f(x)$ so take $b=f(x)+\delta/2$.
- $\impliedby$: trivial.

Now set $U_a=(-\infty, a)$. As per previous equivalence, we have $h^{-1}(U_a)=\bigcup_{b\in\mathbb R}\left(f^{-1}(U_b)\cap g^{-1}(U_{a-b})\right)$ which is open.

So inverse image of all intervals of the form $(-\infty, a)$ for $a\in\mathbb R$ is open. Similarly (symmetrically!), the inverse image of all intervals of the form $(a, +\infty)$ is open. Then it follows that the inverse image of any other open set in $\mathbb R$ is also open.

Answer (score 0):

We only need to prove that $h^{-1}(U)$ is open for $U=(a,b)$ a bounded open interval.

Let $x\in h^{-1}(U).$ Then $a<h(x)<b.$ Let $$r_x=\min(b-h(x),h(x)-a).$$ Then $r_x>0.$

Let $I_{1,x}=(f(x)-r_x/2,f(x)+r_x/2),$ and $I_{2,x}=(g(x)-r_x/2,g(x)+r_x/2).$

Let $V_x=f^{-1}(I_{1,x})\cap g^{-1}(I_{2,x}).$ Then $V_x$ is an open subset of $X$ since it is the intersection of two open subsets of $X.$

Show: $x\in V_x,$ and $h(V_x)\subseteq (a,b).$

So: $$h^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{x\in h^{-1}(U)} V_x$$ is the union of open sets.

---

The sets $I_{1,x}$ and $I_{2,x}$ are essentially what we'd use to prove $x\mapsto (f(x),g(x))$ is continuous **and** to prove that $(p,q)\mapsto p+q$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context and goals, a minimalist argument could be: show that compositions of continuous functions are continuous (easy from the characterization that $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(\hbox{open})$ is open); addition $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous. :) To my taste, consider the latter separately avoids considerable obfuscating notation...